# How do I set the correct date in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to get the correct date format, like this: `24-7-2015`.

`date = new Date("24-7-2015").toString({ dateFormat: 'd-M-yy' })`

but the output of date is then: `Wed Dec 7 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2016`

Thank you

Comment: Have your tried this way:

`new Date(2015,07,24);`

(https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date)

Comment: `Date.toString` has no arguments, you can't pass in a dateFormat ?

Comment: Thank you. But that doenst work

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
var date = new Date("24-7-2015") // If this is not worked than check your local system date format 

document.write(date.getDate() + "-" +  (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear());
```

Let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552493/616535)

If you want to make it easely, like in your example try to use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

```
moment('24-7-2015', 'D-M-YYYY').format('DD-MM-YY');
```